# Specify VS macros in a batch file to run pre or post build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I can use the VS macros like $(ProjectDir) in my pre & post build events. But is there any way I can specify them in a batch file & run the batch file as my pre & post build event?

e.g.

### Before

**Post-Build event**

```
copy $(ProjectDir)foo.txt $(ProjectDir)\out\foo.txt
```

### After

**Post-Build event**

```
CopyFoo.cmd
```

where **CopyFoo.cmd** contains

```
copy $(ProjectDir)foo.txt $(ProjectDir)\out\foo.txt
```

I want to do this to make my build events list more user-friendly to edit/update. Editing a batch file is much easier than editing the build events box in VS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if you can access them or not (becuase `$` has a different meaning inside batch file), but one way would be to pass them as [command line arguments](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) to the batch file. You can access them inside the batch file as %0 - %9.

**Post-Build event**

```
CopyFoo.cmd $(ProjectDir)
```

**Batch file**

```
copy %1foo.txt %1\out\foo.txt
```

Comment: While passing command line-parameters to a batch file (as per Mrchief's solution) Is the correct method, I would like to add that the use of Property-Sheets will allow the user to provide the same pre/post-build event to all the projects in question.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774540(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Compared to the most accepted result, I here provide with a more intuitive way, especially when you have many macro wanted to use.

**Post-Build event**

```
set ENV_ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir)
call CopyFoo.cmd
```

**CopyFoo.cmd**

```
copy %ENV_ProjectDir%\foo.txt %ENV_ProjectDir%\out\foo.txt
```

Side notes:

- (VS2022) I tried to use "set ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir)", but it results in some strange build error for my C# project. Better avoid this naming
- (VS2022) Pre-Build event and Post-Build event env var are seperated. It seems you cannot define in pre-build and use it in post-build

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to just write the commands in an external editor and copy the result to the pre/post build event boxes. Creating .cmd files and passing around parameters sounds more complicated.

Comment: In my case, a batch file saves me from having the same scripts in 50 projects, and having to change all 50 when I need to tweak them.

Comment: Have you considered the use of property sheets to solve that task?

Comment: Hi @JohnBargman , I am very interested to know more about the property sheets approach in lieu of BAT files. Can you point me to an example please? thanks.